# Example of Leibniz algebra that is not a Lie algebra.

Tags: lie-algebras

I need an example of Leibniz  algebra that is not a Lie algebra.

I found the following example but it seems that is not true:

$L $ is a $k $-vector space and { $e_1,e_2 $} a basis and the billinear form is defined as follows

$[e_1,e_2]=[e_2,e_2]=e_1$ and $[e_1,e_1]=[e_2,e_1]=0$.

But $[[e_1,e_1],e_2] \neq [[e_1,e_2],e_1] +[[e_1,[e_1,e_2]] $ because

RS=$[0,e_2] $ and LS=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side equals the left hand side in this case, because $[0,e_2]=0$, since it is bilinear. So it should work.

Comment: Can you argument  why [$0,e_2]$=0?

Comment: I already did. It is bilinear. What does this mean? In particular we have   $f(0,y)=0\cdot f(0,y)=0$, from $f(\lambda x,y)=\lambda f(x,y)$.